# Converting a Spring MVC Web Application into Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, single-page-application

Currently I'm working on a Spring MVC web application in which for front end design we use JSP, EXTJS, jQuery, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX and few other UI libraries. This application contains thousands of jsps and almost each jsp is associated with its own CSS and Js files for UI design and server communication. I have to convert this project into a single page application to improve the UI experience to the user.

I want to know which things needs to be taken care of from UI point of view while converting a huge web application into single page application. For example, if I want to use Javascript, I will have to create good namespaces. Please point me to right direction about what should I study or any good document about Single Page Application development.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to use something like AngularJS?

Comment: We are already using ExtJs framework, currently we do not plan to move to Angular as it will cost much time.

Comment: @Optio, if u think the significance to move to Angular Js is more than the time cost then I can think about it.

Comment: Significance depends on many factors. Unfortunately I don't know anything about EXTJS and how big your project is, but half year ago we also had JSP, jQuery, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX... It was terrible. Now we have AngularJs. But main idea was in decrease requests amount, increase page speed. We actively use browser Local Storage. We thrown out all JSP, we left only html pages. For some features we use sockets. AngularJs not the only way.

Comment: Project size is huge, and about ExtJs, we have extensively used it for UI components like Grid, Charts, TabPanels, Popups, Tooltips and few other. The problem is we did not use ExtJs in all parts, only where it was needed. So other screens are left with only plain Js and jQuery. I think what you did is required as to increase the response time and performance. If you can elaborate more on few topics in answer I can accept that.

Comment: Actually we divide our project on two servers: backend (Java, Spring MVC, Mongodb), and frontend (NodeJs + Angular + WebPack). Backend now doesn't have any views, only Rest. And we don't use jQuery (only hardcore, only native js ))